# Child object calls siblings' methods

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, backbone-views

I have the following structure:

```
var PopupView = Backbone.View.extend({
  el:'#shade',
  events:{
    'click .popup-cancel': 'hide',
    'click .popup-commit': 'commit',
  },
  show: function(){
    ...
  },
  hide: function(){
    ...
  },
  initialize: function(){
    _.bindAll(this, 'show','hide','commit');
  }
});

var Popup1 = PopupView.extend({
  render: function(){
    ...
  },
  commit: function(){
    console.log('1');
    ...
  },
});

var Popup2 = PopupView.extend({
  render: function(){
    ...
  },
  commit: function(){
    console.log('2');
    ...
  },
});
```

The problem is that when I click `.popup-commit` from one of the popups, it actually triggers the methods of *both* of them. I've tried moving the declaration of `events` and `initialize()` up into the child classes, but that doesn't work.

What's going on, and how can I fix it (so that the `commit` method of only the view I'm triggering it on gets fired)?

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is right here:

```
el:'#shade'
```

in your `PopupView` definition. That means that every single instance of `PopupView` or its subclasses (except of course those that provide their own `el`) will be bound to the same DOM node and they will all be listening to events on on `id="shade"` element.

You need to give each view its own `el`. I'd recommend against ever setting `el` in a view definition like that. I think you'll have a better time if you let each view create (and destroy) its own `el`. If you do something like:

```
var PopupView = Backbone.View.extend({
  className: 'whatever-css-class-you-need',
  tagName: 'div', // or whatever you're using to hold your popups.
  attributes: { /* whatever extra attributes you need on your el */ },
  //...
});
```

then your views will each get their own `el`. See the [`Backbone.View` documentation](http://backbonejs.org/#View) for more information on these properties.